# Missing DLL attempts to load when a program starts - Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, dll

Windows pops up the "Unable To Load Component" warning whenever any program starts.
The DLL is netexmls.dll which I can't find anywhere in the registry or on google. Most programs still load once the warning is cleared and run as normal though some won't run at all, Firefox, chrome, paintbrush.

If I place a different DLL in the system32 folder I get a missing procedure call which is also non existent on google or in the registry.

This also happens when I boot into safe mode. I have tried sfc /scannow and a couple of system restores but to no avail.

I am at a loss as to how to stop it. Any suggestions?

[image: Warning Message]

Comment: You should post this at superuser.com.  This is not programming related.

Comment: thanks i believe someone else has done that for me already though. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the dll listed by [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)?

If not, you might try running [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on an app that causes the warning and see if it shows up there.

Comment: I tried autoruns and it does not come up in there. I will try dependancy walker now...

Comment: using dependancy walker I found that imm32.dll had an extra function added to it which called upon the missing dll. I replaced the dll with the imm32.dll from another xp machine and it works now. Thank you Sean